# Prevent database from being cleaned up on re-deploy

Tags: google-app-engine

When I re-deploy an app to the app engine, the app the existing data in the datastore is cleaned-up.
How do I prevent this from happening?

Update:1 I am using Java, 1.6.3. This is on the production system.

Comment: In production or on local dev server?

Comment: what SDK? python, java, go? what tools you're using to run?

Comment: in production server and language used is java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the datastore in production does not get flushed if you redeploy. if you change model definitions and structures it might be that the data you need does not belong to the new(er) model definition...
if you are speaking about the datastore on your local machine start the dev server with the

```
--datastore_path=/tmp/myapp_datastore myapp
```

if you are using python. don't know what the equivalent for the java SDK is.
you need to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you are changing the app name just prior to deployment (so you're deploying to the correct app).  But previous data in your *local* datastore was stored under the prior name.  If you don't change the app name back before using the local datastore again, it can appear as though the data has disappeared.